# Saprfc connection issue

Tags: php, saprfc

I 'm having issues configuring the `saprfc_open` to actually connect.

`saprfc_open` does not support the `saprouter` string (i.e. unlike java).

How do you actually make it connect if you need to use the `saprouter` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems saprouter is not supported by the extension, so I had to switch to the java connector for this part.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same as a direct connection, except you put the router string into the ASHOST parameter, instead of the just the system hostname/IP:

`/H/<SAP router hostname or IP>/S/<SAP router port>/H/<SAP system hostname or IP>`

For example:

`/H/saprouter.mycomp.local/S/3299/H/sapsystem.mycomp.local`

Comment: Thank you very much. From the ini file I have: `ASHOST: 10.x.x.x` and `SAPROUTER: /H/194.x.x.x/W/somestring/H/` I tried using this in `ASHOST: /H/194.x.x.x/W/somestring/H/10.x.x.x`,  but it did not work :(.

Comment: I've done some more searching and one thing I saw coming up a couple times, was to use the **MSHOST** parameter instead of the ASHOST one. Perhaps you could give that a shot using the `/H/194.x.x.x/W/somestring/H/10.x.x.x` string.